# SQL query slow after server change

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, sum

I have moved my page to a new server and have stumbled upon a query-problem. 
The query below runs fine on the first server. However, when importing the data from the tables to the new server the loading times takes about 4-5sec instead of 0.2.

Ive been searching for days now. And would really appriciate a hint or two in the right direction.

back_time consists of 6000 rows and back_ao of ~600rows. If I can run the query in a more efficient way please point that out aswell.

New mysqlversion:  5.1.70

Old mysqlversion:  5.1.60

I have tried to repair the tables.

```
SELECT sum(back_time.Tm), 
       sum(back_time.Tti), 
       sum(back_time.Ton), 
       sum(back_time.Tto), 
       sum(back_time.Tfr), 
       sum(back_time.Tlo), 
       sum(back_time.Tso), 
       sum(back_time.OTm), 
       sum(back_time.OTti), 
       sum(back_time.OTon), 
       sum(back_time.OTto), 
       sum(back_time.OTfr), 
       sum(back_time.OTlo), 
       sum(back_time.OTso) 
FROM back_time 
 WHERE back_time.ssao 
  IN (
      select back_ao.ssao 
        from back_ao 
           where back_ao.status = 1
     )
```

Comment: Did indexes go missing?

Comment: @GoatCO When I check at the tables the indexes looks the same as in the old mysqlserver.

Answer (score 0):

Is your data physically stored on a similar storage support? Hard drive read speed or geographical distance (if there are network drives) between the server and the storage may impact load speed.

Comment: First server is on a shared webhosting company. New server is a VPS. The query runs fine for another user(same mysqlserver and exactly the same code). The only difference is that the data is inserted from scratch and not imported.

Comment: So you say that the query is slow only for your user?

Comment: Yes, for one single user. Exactly the same code. I am running a service. At the new server I have 2 users(for eg). One with the data inserted manually(from using the service) and the other I imported the data from my old location. And the query is only running slow on the last imported one. @andrei-nicusan

Comment: How did you import the data? Aren't the 2 users running queries against the same set of data?

Comment: Import/export function in phpmyadmin of the data. same with the tables but from the new server. no, different databases, same mysqlserver. @andrei-nicusan

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the time down to ~.4-.9 sec by adding a couple of more index to it. It has the be possible to get it down even?